# Exchange Server Webdav: How to retrieve the unique id of new items created

Tags: webdav, exchange-server-2003, appointment

I am creating the appointments using WebDav in Exchange server 2003 and it is working perfectly fine. I however want to get an handle for the newly created items for future user like setting custom property/deleting etc.

How to get back a unique ID or something for the newly create the appointment? Does the PROPPATCH return any value??

Thanks
Shreedhar

Comment: I read about a property called permanenturl which will be unique for each item in exchange server. But how to get this value back from exchange server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create new item server returns MultiStatus. Inside MultiStatus response is item's url. Keep this url for later use (to delete/update item).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142976(v=exchg.65).aspx

There is also a library with clean design from Independentsoft which implements WebDAV protocol for Exchange. It also returns item's url when you create new item.

Comment: Sorry for being so late, but you are right. The item's URL itself is unique and can be used as a unique id. Thanks for sharing.